# Wrap SCSS selector shortcut

Tags: sass, emmet

So I use emmet quite a bit now and love it. I especially like how you can wrap abbreviations around already existing code.  I was wondering if there was a way in emmet or another plugin or package, that would allow me to wrap a scss selector? So if

```
.child{
    *styles*
}
```

already exists and I want to wrap .parent around it quickly and easily to make

```
.parent{
 .child{
  *styles*
 }
}
```

is there a shortcut or hotkey or plugin or something that does this? If it helps at all I use Atom.

Comment: Are you just looking to `@extend` existing classes via sass?

Comment: No.  I suppose its less of a scss question and more of a work environment question.  Much like atom-wrap-in-tag package for HTML I was wondering if there is something of a SCSS version where I could highlight .child and its styles and its styles, then type in .parent somewhere and it will wrap .parent around .child

Comment: I couldn't find anything :/ -- maybe you can make your own plugin for it :)

Comment: Seems to be the case. thought I'd ask first anyway. thanks guys